# how to use a @EnvironmentObject in combination with a List

Tags: swiftui

The code for the basic app from Anlil's answer works fine. If I edit the datamodel to be more like mine, with a multidimensional String array, I get something like:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var dm: DataManager

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
               NavigationLink(destination:AddView().environmentObject(self.dm)) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill").font(.system(size: 30))
                }
                ForEach(dm.array, id: \.self) { item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(item: item)) {
                        Text(item[0])
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var item : [String] = ["", "", ""]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(item[0])
            Text(item[1])
            Text(item[2])
        }
    }
}

struct AddView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var dm: DataManager
    @State var item0 : String = "" // needed by TextField
    @State var item1 : String = "" // needed by TextField
    @State var item2 : String = "" // needed by TextField
    @State var item : [String] = ["", "", ""]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Write something", text: $item0)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
            TextField("Write something", text: $item1)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
            TextField("Write something", text: $item2)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
            Button(action: {
                self.item = [self.item0, self.item1, self.item2]
                print(self.item)
                self.dm.array.append(self.item)
            }) {
                Text("Save")
            }
        }
    }
}

class DataManager: BindableObject {
    var willChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    var array : [[String]] = [["Item 1","Item 2","Item 3"],["Item 4","Item 5","Item 6"],["Item 7","Item 8","Item 9"]] {
        didSet {
            willChange.send()
        }
    }
}
```

There are no errors and the code runs as expected. Before I'm going to rewrite my own code (with the lessons I've learned solar) it would be nice if the code could be checked.

I'm really impressed with SwiftUI!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your "source of truth" is an array of some "model instances", and you just need to read values, you can pass those instance around like before:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var dm: DataManager

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(dm.array, id: \.self) { item in
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(item: item)) {
                    Text(item)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var item : String
    var body: some View {
        Text(item)
    }
}

class DataManager: BindableObject {
    var willChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    let array = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]
}


#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environmentObject(DataManager())
    }
}
#endif
```

You need to pass the EnvironmentObject only if some views are able to manipulate the data inside the instances... in this case you can easily update the EnvironmentObject's status and everything will auto-magically updated everywhere!

The code below shows a basic App with "list", "detail" and "add", so you can see 'environment' in action (the only caveat is that you have to manually tap < Back after tapped the Save button). Try it and you'll see the list that will magically update.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var dm: DataManager

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
               NavigationLink(destination:AddView().environmentObject(self.dm)) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill").font(.system(size: 30))
                }
                ForEach(dm.array, id: \.self) { item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(item: item)) {
                        Text(item)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var item : String
    var body: some View {
        Text(item)
    }
}

struct AddView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var dm: DataManager
    @State var item : String = "" // needed by TextField
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Write something", text: $item)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
            Button(action: {
                self.dm.array.append(self.item)
            }) {
                Text("Save")
            }
        }
    }
}

class DataManager: BindableObject {
    var willChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    var array : [String] = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"] {
        didSet {
            willChange.send()
        }
    }
}


#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environmentObject(DataManager())
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: Hi Enlil, I edited my question with the current datamodel. If I understood you correctly I have to adapt my datamodel to an array (see code above). And then... what do I have to do with the receiver/sender part?

Comment: Hi Enlil, I edited my question once again... trying to update the datamodel to have more dimensions.

Comment: Hi Enlil, the code works now. Can you please check it before I rewrite my own code? Thank you for taking the time to teach.